# Running time of Algorithme for Rookies

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, pseudocode

I have made this Pseudocode

```
A = 2,1,8,4,3,6

n = 6
i = 1
H = 2
inv = 0

while H <= n                    

    if A[i] > A[H] && !H = n
        inv = inv + 1
        H = H + 1
    else if A[i] > A[H] && H = n
        inv = inv + 1
        i = i + 1
        H = i + 1
    else if A[i] < A[H] && !H = n 
        H = H + 1
    else if A[i] < A[H] && H = n
        i = i + 1 
        H = i + 1

print inv
```

Now I Need to calculate the Running time of this Algorithme. I would really be eternally greateful if someone would take baby steps with me and tell me to the core how you calculate the running time of this example.

I have read lots of guides and books on this subject. All mentioning something about costs, units, times, constants, etc. All did it just make me more confused. I now turn to you guys as a last resort in hopes of getting to understand this matter fully.

Comment: Do you have a tutor to do this for you?

Comment: i do not have a tudor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming `n` is size of the input.

Notice that at every step in the loop, `H` is always increased by 1. This loop will run till `H` reaches `n`. Thus the number of iterations in the loop is `n-1` since `H` is set to 2 at the beginning.

Also, every operation in the loop is `O(1)`. Thus the program runs in `O(N)`.

**EDIT**:

To answer Nulle's comment, `c1,c2,...` refers to constants. Each constant represents a certain amount of time taken. For example, the `for` loop might take `c1` time to run through 1 iteration of the loop. It might take `c2` time to output the answer, initialise the variables, setting up the loop etc. Thus the time taken for this to run is `c1 * n + c2`. We do not know exactly what `c1` and `c2` are since they vary from platform to platform. For more info, you can refer to this [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation)

Comment: i get that aswell. Can you do a small example for me? You dont have to do my example if ya find it too time taking. As i understand it the result needs to be something like t(n)= c1*n + c2*(n-2)...etc But what number is c1 in a given example? in my example n = 6 but how do i measure c1, c2, etc.

Comment: ohh i get it now. So i wont end up having t(n) = 2 or something. The closet i can get in my example is for instance t(n) = c1*6 + c2*(6-1).... and when i get to the while loop it is ...c5*(6*(6+1)/2-1) + c6*(6(6-1)/2-1)... is that correctly understood?